# Litho Crash on Start

Tags: android, facebook, litho

I'm developing android application that require some complex RecyclerView UI that why i give a try on Facebook's Litho but even samples crash seem to crash on my old phone HTC Desire x run android 4.1 but on new phone running 6.0 it's work does litho doesn't support android prior to 4.1 jellybeans ?
[debug log gist](https://gist.github.com/mucyomiller/d10e6371808c348a03ad95e4a697355b)

Comment: [Litho apparently requires API15 (4.0.3) minimum](https://github.com/facebook/litho/blob/master/build.gradle) So apparently, it's not a version issue, but might be some other compatibility problem. Did you try to run the app on another phone or an emulator that runs Android 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it's a litho problem. It might be a multidex problem though. 
Try [adding support for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to your app and see if this works.